# Implementing reactive values in Regression using Shiny

Tags: shiny, regression, reactive-programming

I am currently working on a project aiming to create an interface which can do statistical analysis. A good reference to my goal would be something like the following website: https://rich.shinyapps.io/regression/

The issues I have regard a reactive Regression. The user is supposed to choose data input which will then be used in a Regression. Unfortunately I have to create subsets of the data frame before being able to process the input due to the conception of the data...

This input is stored in the variables X, Y and Z and can be shown using "paste", but the regression doesn't work.`enter code here`

Any suggestions?

```
library("shiny")
```

ui <-  fluidPage((pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("Dynamic Analysis"),

```
  sidebarPanel(

  selectInput (
  inputId = "Country", label = "Choose a country", choices = c(levels(eurostat$GEO))
  ),

  selectInput (
  inputId = "Indice1", label = "Choose a dependent variable X", choices = c(levels(eurostat$INDIC_NA), 1)
  ),
  selectInput (
  inputId = "Indice2", label = "Choose an independent variable Y", choices = c(levels(eurostat$INDIC_NA), 1)
  ),
  selectInput (
  inputId = "Indice3", label = "Choose an independent variable Z", choices = c(levels(eurostat$INDIC_NA), 1)
  ),
  selectInput (
  inputId = "Unit1", label = "Choose a Unit", choices = c(levels(eurostat$UNIT), 1)
  )
  ),

  mainPanel(tableOutput("regTab"),

  textOutput("test")
  )

   # mainPanel("Table",tableOutput="table")
  )))

  #This function is used to subset the desired data from the dataset
  subsetting_num = function(Country, Indice, Unit, npar=TRUE,print=TRUE){
  as.numeric(gsub(",", "" ,droplevels(subset(subset(subset(ES2, GEO== Country, Value!=0), INDIC_NA== Indice), UNIT == Unit)$Value)))
  }
```

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

```
X = reactive({subsetting_num(input$Country, input$Indice1, input$Unit1)})
Y = reactive({subsetting_num(input$Country, input$Indice2, input$Unit1)})
Z = reactive({subsetting_num(input$Country, input$Indice3, input$Unit1)})


# regression formula
runRegression <- reactive({
lm(X ~ Y + Z)
})

#Summary Regression
output$regTab <- renderTable({
if(!is.null(X)){
  summary(runRegression())$coefficients
} else {
  print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
}
```

})

```
#Depict the reactive values
output$test <- renderText({
paste("Subset", X())

})
```

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Comment: I have noticed that in the lm call the X, Y and Z variable are not called as functions. Have you tried lm(X() ~ Y() + Z())?

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank you though!

Comment: Give me a hint on how to upvote your comment and I'll do it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if you find some of my other answers useful you can upvote those. If not then some other time... thanks anyway.